# JSGrid - Load JSON data - "Not Found"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsgrid

I have a problem populating a jsgrid from with JSON data and I have scaled down the code to a very minimal implementation but it is still not working.
I can see in the Chrome debugger that the REST call returns data on this format

{data: [{ "Name":"MyAccount"}]}

Anyone who can see what is wrong?

```html
<script>
   

    $(function () {

        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            height: "auto",
            width: "100%",

            sorting: true,
            paging: false,
            autoload: true,
           
            controller: {
                loadData: function (filter) {
                    console.log(filter);
                    return $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "http://localhost:8888/GetListJSGrid",
                        data: filter,
                        dataType: "json"
                    });
                }
            },
           
            fields: [
             { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150 }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

The format of returned data should be an array of items, not a JSON object with `data` field.

Note that for loading by page (`pageLoading: true`) this format is different: `{ data: [arrayOfItems], totalCount: amountOfItems }`.

For the code above you could do the following:

```
loadData: function (filter) {
    console.log(filter);
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/GetListJSGrid",
        data: filter,
        dataType: "json"
    }).then(function(result) {
        return result.data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved. It seems that the documentation is not updated for JSGrid or that I have missed something here.

By comparing the response from the link below that is working in JSGrid

[ODataTest](https://services.odata.org/V3/%28S%283mnweai3qldmghnzfshavfok%29%29/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json)

I noticed that the following JSON is accepted by JSGrid
{"value": [{ "Name":"MyAccount"}]}