# JS Grid not showing data in table

Tags: jsgrid

I forced to change my nearly finished project developed on Filemaker to Open Source due to licensing issues. So I have to learn PHP, Javascript and all that stuff while programming. I am struggling now for 2 weeks with this issue. I have a php file with my JS Grid table which is also visible:

My code for the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#contacts_table').jsGrid({

    width: "100%",
    height: "457px",

    pageLoading: false,
    filtering: true,
    inserting: true,
    editing: true,
    sorting: true,
    paging: true,
    autoload: true,
    pageSize: 10,
    pageButtonCount: 2,
    confirmDeleting: true,
    noDataContent: "Not found",

    deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete data?",

    controller: {

        loadData: function (filter) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "fetch_contacts_supplier_JS_Grid.php",
                data: filter,
                dataType: "json"
            });
        },
    },

    fields: [
        {name: "Id",        type: "number",     width: 10,  visible: false},
        {name: "SupplierId",type: "number",     width: 10,  visible: false},
        {name: "Title",     type: "text",       width: 10,  validate: "required"},
        {name: "Name",      type: "text",       width: 30,  validate: "required"},
        {name: "Surname",   type: "text",       width: 30,  validate: "required"},
        {name: "Position",  type: "text",       width: 20,  validate: "required"},
        {name: "Phone",     type: "text",       width: 30},
        {name: "Mobile",    type: "text",       width: 30},
        {name: "Fax",       type: "text",       width: 30},
        {name: "Email",     type: "text",       width: 30},
        {name: "Active",    type: "checkbox",   width: 10,  validate: "required"},
        {                   type: "control",    width: 10}
    ]

});
});
```

My code for the DB select (which works) fetch_contacts_supplier_JS_Grid.php:

```
 if($method == 'GET') {
    If ($statement = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM suppliers_contacts WHERE _fk_SuppliersID = 1")) {
        if ($statement->execute()) {
            $result = $statement->get_result(); // fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $new_array[] = array(
                    'Id' => $row['_pk_SuppliersContactsID'],
                    'SupplierId' => $row['_fk_SuppliersID'],
                    'Title' => $row['Title'],
                    'Name' => $row['Name'],
                    'Surname' => $row['Surname'],
                    'Position' => $row['Job_Position'],
                    'Phone' => $row['PhoneFixed'],
                    'Mobile' => $row['PhoneCell'],
                    'Fax' => $row['PhoneFax'],
                    'Email' => $row['Email'],
                    'Active' => $row['Active']
                );
            }
        }
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($new_array);
    } ELSE {
        echo $link->error;
    }
 }
```

The array I get in the console:

> [{"Id":1,"SupplierId":1,"Title":"Mr.","Name":"Jens","Surname":"Dietzel","Position":"Owner","Phone":"145754","Mobile":"86868","Fax":"4368843","Email":"jens@jd-sd.com.na","Active":"checked"},{"Id":2,"SupplierId":1,"Title":"Mrs.","Name":"Karen","Surname":"Mann","Position":"Manager","Phone":"24525","Mobile":"745754","Fax":"544","Email":"karen@test.de","Active":"checked"}]

But the table shows `not found`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not found means what ? The data is showing as not found or anything else ? Its unclear. Provide more details about the error

Comment: possibly it's the same kind of cause, see the original author answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42880678/2368696